# d3.js: How to update chart with click with mouse scrubber tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent

I'm working on updating data dynamically with a click while maintaining a mouseover scrubber to highlight (i.e. append) the data to text elements. I am able to get the initial data and scrubber to work based on this helpful tutorial: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/my-favourite-tooltip-method-for-line.html.

My next step was to update my data (i.e. paths and axis) based on a button click. I used this tutorial: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html. However, I am only able to update the paths and axis but the mouseover event is till capturing the old data.

Maybe I still haven't fully grasped the idea of enter, update, exit? Anyone know how to update the mouseover scrubber when the path elements update via the mouse click?

Answer (score 0):

On [D3js's website](http://d3js.org/) there are plenty of tutorials that explain very clearly how `enter`, `update`,and `exit` work. Personally I prefer [this one](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/).

Hope it helps.